# Accessing JMeter Variables from the JUnit Test Case

Tags: junit, jmeter-plugins

`JUnitSampler junitSampler = new JUnitSampler();
        String UserId=junitSampler.getThreadContext().getVariables().get("foo");
        driver.findElement(By.name("username")).sendKeys(UserId);`

I see an error (red squiggly lines): The method getThreadContext().getVariables() is undefined for the type JUnitSampler
how to solve??[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SQJ4i.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you have [ApacheJMeter_junit](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.jmeter/ApacheJMeter_junit/4.0) library in your project classpath? If not - you will need to add it in order to be able to use [JMeter API](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/index.html) methods.

If you cannot - it is still possible using [Java Reflection](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/java/javareflection-1536171.html) but will be way more tricky.

Another option is considering switching to [JSR223 Sampler](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_Sampler), in the majority of cases valid Java code will be valid Groovy code and you will have `vars` shorthand for [JMeterVariables](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/threads/JMeterVariables.html) class where you will be able to easily read and write JMeter Variables.

See [Apache Groovy - Why and How You Should Use It](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/groovy-new-black) article for more information on using Groovy scripting in JMeter tests.

Comment: first, I was have an error in JUnitSampler junitSampler = new JUnitSampler(); line then I have added ApacheJMeter_junit jar from Apache-JMeter-3.1\lib\ext then error red squiggly line moved to nextline to junitSampler.getThreadContext().getVariables()